# Google Analytics Site Search Config Questions

Tags: google-analytics, web-analytics

We have site search set up on our site, with the correct query parameter, however, we are not seeing site search data. See the image [here](https://productforums.google.com/forum/?utm_medium=email&utm_source=footer#!msg/analytics/fYZBP0jSlcw/_U6tRGAg3O8J) for how our config is set up.

The URL for our search page looks like this https://www.premierinc.com/?s=Example.

We know there has been search traffic. Internal users (myself included) have performed a number of searches. The tag has been live for over a week, so processing delay shouldn't be an issue.

I've also triple checked that I'm on the correct view in GA.

Any ideas?

Comment: I'm not seeing the Google Analytics tracking code on the page you link to. Are you seeing data in GA for other site metrics, like visits, page views, bounces, etc.?

Comment: Hi Khilley. The tracking code is there and we do see data on other reports/metrics.  You can see the request to GA servers.  We use a tag management service that doesn't work with some GA detection plugins.  But it is there.

Comment: Ok. What query parameter value are you using in the GA Site Search Settings?

Comment: We're using the character s.  See the image in the other thread for complete config.

Comment: Got it, sorry I see that now. Can you try including the GA code without using Tealium (inserting it as part of the site HTML)? Wondering if Tealium is stripping out the necessary information to hand off to GA...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So it turns out that GA favors the document path (dp) parameter over the document location (dl) parameter.  So although the search term was in the payload sent to GA, it was promptly ignored when it got there :)

Moral, if you use dp, you probably need to use dq as well.

(Thanks to Kim Towne on the [GA forums](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/analytics/fYZBP0jSlcw) for helping me figure this one out).

Comment: Could you add the link to the post in the GA forum?